# Pandas not dividing length of cells

Tags: python, pandas

Been struggling with this problem for a long time. I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[dataframe pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Zr3W.png)

I'm trying to divide the length of each 'counter' by the length of each 'content'. I thought this would be fairly straightforward. So far I've tried:

```
reviews['diversity'] = reviews['counter'].apply(lambda x: 0 if len(x) == 0 else float(len(x)) / float(len(reviews['content'][x])))
```

as well as using `x['content']`. I get the massive error message `KeyError: "None of [['aberfeldy', 'recorded', 'their', 'debut', 'young', 'forever', 'using', 'a', 'single', 'microphone', 'good', 'for', 'them', 'in', 'that', 'spirit', 'i', 'cut', 'short', 'my', 'obligatory', 'introduction', 'and', 'bring', 'you', 'straight', 'to', 'the', 'edinburgh', 'group', 'lovelorn', 'unfortunately', 'still', 'heart', 'exposed', 'by', 'oh', 'production', 'love', 'is', 'verb', 'noun', 'as', 'well', 'find', 'it', 'dictionary', 'under', 'l', 'little', 'witticism', 'comes', 'from', 'an', 'arrow', 'written', 'sung', 'riley', 'briggs', 'based', 'on', 'one', 'photo', 'looks', 'like', 'anthony', 'michael', 'hall', 'though', 'his', 'vocals', 'chart', 'fairly', 'standard', 'indie', 'course', 'borrowing', 'neil', 'friend', 'ben', 'gibbard', 'what', 'do', 'plain', 'sensitive', 'guys', 'everywhere', 'listen', 'some', 'of', 'best', 'friends', 'are', 'favorite', 'albums', 'consist', 'campfire', 'singalongs', 'bands', 'with', 'modest', 'acoustic', 'guitar', 'chops', 'cute', 'names', 'accents', 'but', 'those', 'lyrics', 'no', 'band', 'would', 'sing', 'such', 'words', 'deserves', 'easily', 'made', 'comparisons', 'fellow', 'scots', 'belle', '', 'sebastian', 'or', 'even', 'camera', 'obscura', 'let', 'alone', 'earnest', 'aussies', 'lucksmiths', 'compare', 'twee', 'progenitors', 'pastels', 'talulah', 'gosh', 'owe', 'me', 'your', 'cardigan', 'moniker', 'nipped', 'scottish', 'vacation', 'destination', 'practically', 'beg', 'name', 'there', 'need', 'encourage', 'throughout', 'record', 'shows', 'predisposition', 'toward', 'bungling', 'old', 'english', 'teachers', 'motto', 'show', 'not', 'tell', 'this', 'may', 'be', 'result', 'medical', 'condition', 'dyslexia', 'which', 'case', 'we', 'should', 'hold', 'our', 'snark', 'seems', 'guy', 'can', 'open', 'mouth', 'without', 'saying', 'nothing', 'so', 'sad', 'leaving', 'he', 'sings', 'out', 'lonely', 'now', 'she', 'gone', 'adds', 'tie', 'teems', 'vivid', 'storytelling', 'goes', 'rhyme', 'sacred', 'wasted', 'reasons', 'until', 'somewhere', 'editor', 'rhyming', 'loses', 'her', 'job', 'often', 'at', 'when', 'they', 'stumble', 'beyond', 'trite', 'infantilism', 'first', 'vegetarian', 'restaurant', 'lopes', 'along', 'winning', 'tangled', 'up', 'blue', 'strums', 'accented', 'subtle', 'fiddles', 'lovely', 'boy', 'harmonies', 'seemingly', 'aiming', 'album', 'cheerful', 'unpretentious', 'look', 'everyday', 'here', 'finally', 'makes', 'interesting', 'way', 'dance', 'kitchen', 'says', 'willing', 'see', 'where', 'takes', 'him', 'then', 'proclaims', 'sometimes', 'believe', 'human', 'duck', 'cover', 'speaking', 'aliens', 'heliopolis', 'night', 'next', 'track', 'incidentally', 'its', 'second', 'whimsical', 'spaceship', 'song', 'complete', 'nose', 'perfect', 'unique', 'yeah', 'was', 'means', 'warm', 'pop', 'heats', 'headphones', 'veritable', 'help', 'root', 'begins', 'everyone', 'because', 'last', 'thing', 'world', 'needs', 'another', 'batch', 'sullen', 'scenesters', 'yet', 'any', 'relationship', 'just', 'someone', 'doesn', 'mean', 'back', 'beautiful', 'gibbs', 'tells', 'us', 'tender', 'moment', 'probably', 'if', 'hope', 'gets', 'laid']] are in the [index]"`.

I've tried:

```
def diverse(x):
    if len(x) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return float(len(x)) / float(len(reviews['clean'][x]))

reviews['diverse'] = reviews['counter'].apply(diverse)
```

and get the same thing.

I've tried using applymap with `reviews['diversity'] = reviews.applymap(lambda x: 0 if len(x) == 0 else  float(len(reviews['counter'][x])) / float(len(reviews['content'][x])))`

and get `("object of type 'int' has no len()", 'occurred at index Unnamed: 0')`.

And yet if I just do `float(len(reviews['counter'][4])) / float(len(reviews['clean'][4]))`, I get `0.634375`.

Any help is much appreciated.

edit: I tried:

```
def test(x, y):
    for row, item in x.iteritems():
        x = float(len(item))
    for row, item in y.iteritems():
        if len(item) == 0:
            return (0)
        else:
            y = float(len(item))
            return (x/y)`
```

When I used "print" instead of "return", it gave me all the values. But return only divides the length of the first row, which seems really weird?

Comment: Do you want to divide the length of each value in the counter dictionary? Or literally the length of the dictionary (i.e. the number of unique words?)

Comment: The second; I want to divide the length of the dictionary itself. I actually got a function ALMOST working, I'll include it in the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is toy example I constructed to show how to do what you are asking:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame([['hello world i am a computer'],
                   ['hello i am a computer too hello computer']], 
                   columns=['content'])

df['counter'] = df.content.str.split().apply(Counter)
df

# returns:
                                 content                                              counter
             hello world i am a computer    {'am': 1, 'hello': 1, 'computer': 1, 'world': ...
hello i am a computer too hello computer    {'am': 1, 'hello': 2, 'computer': 2, 'a': 1, '...
```

This line answers the question as you phrased it:

```
df['diversity'] = df.content.str.len() / df.counter.apply(len)
```

But I think what you really wanted was to break the strings in `content` into a list of words by splitting on the space character.  In that case, you probably want:

```
df['diversity'] = df.content.str.split().apply(len) / df.counter.apply(len)
```

Comment: Can't believe that worked so easily. Thanks much, and as a favor, can you look at what I added in the edit of this post, with the test(x,y) function? The fact that print works and return doesn't has been driving me almost psychotic for the past 30 minutes.

Comment: When you use `return` it stops execution of the function and returns the value.  It is telling python "ok, i have done what i needed to do, here is the value you asked for".  If you want to return all of the values, you should create an empty list within the function, append values to the list, and then return the list.

Comment: For some reason I was under the impression that it returned all values. Thanks for clarifying :)